# Can any malware access the OSX keychain data

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, security, keychain

I'm working on security project, in project i have sensitive data that i would like to store in OS X key-chain access. I'm able to add the data programmatically into the OS X key-chain access by using [RHKeychain](https://github.com/heardrwt/RHKeychain)  ... but after doing lot of research, OS X key-chain data can also accessible ( [LINK](http://www.cio.com/article/2392491/security0/tool-allows-mac-os-x-hackers-with-root-access-to-easily-extract-keychain-data.html)    and [LINK1](http://juusosalonen.com/post/30923743427/breaking-into-the-os-x-keychain)    )
 by the malware. can any one have any idea on this.. i need to fulfill the following actions

1) Is "OS X Key-chain" data accessible by malware?
2) If Yes, what is the best approach to secure "OS X key-chain access" data.
3) What is the best approach other than the "OS X key-chain access"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it not programming related but about general computing security. There's a site for exactly that at http://security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're using the data for, the design of Keychain Access is to allow the user to access the things in there without typing any passwords (because the user has already logged in). If that doesn't suit your needs, then you can take a look at [security transforms](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/SecTransformPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010801) which performs common encryption which should be enough for your case.